# PHP Laravel composer illuminate/cache conflict with another require

Tags: php, laravel, caching, model, composer-php

I have the app in Laravel 5.6 and need to cache some models. I found only one package that can provide this (genealabs/laravel-model-caching), but it requires package illuminate/cache 8.0.* that is in conflict with some another require:

**Problem 1**

- Root composer.json requires genealabs/laravel-model-caching ^0.11.1 -> satisfiable by genealabs/laravel-model-caching[0.11.1].
- genealabs/laravel-model-caching 0.11.1 requires illuminate/cache ^8.0 -> found illuminate/cache[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.

**Is there a way how to find out which package is it in a conflict with?**

My composer.json requires are:

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "anouar/paypalpayment": ">=3.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.5",
        "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "^2.5",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.6",
        "hazestudio/laravel-gopay-sdk": "^0.1.5",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "tcg/voyager": "^1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.4",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If there is any package requiring `illuminate/cache` in v8 and you are using `laravel/framework` in v5.6, I would assume that this is the root cause :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is package version issue. You need to find genealabs/laravel-model-caching version which is support with laravel 5.6.*